# (Lagrange) dual problem of minimizing l1-norm of a matrix

Tags: optimization, matrix-calculus, nonlinear-optimization

I have to figure out the Lagrange dual of a constrained matrix $\ell_1$-norm minimization problem:

$$\operatorname{minimize}_{\ Y} ||A(Y)||_1$$
subject to
\begin{align} \operatorname{diag}(Y) &= \vec{c}\\
           Y &\succcurlyeq 0,
\end{align}

where $Y$ and $A(Y)$ are square matrices in $R^{n\times n}$, $A(Y)$ is linear in $Y$

I know the dual norm of $\ell_1$-norm is the infinity norm. But I am struggling with the operator to extract the diagonal entries of $Y$. This problem appears in several contexts like matrix completion, filtering etc. Can some one please help.

Comment: You haven't defined the function $A(Y)$.  Is it linear in the elements of $Y$?

Comment: Let $\odot$ denote the elementwise/Hadamard product, $I$ the identity matrix, and ${\tt1}$ the all-ones vector. Then $${\rm diag}(Y)=(Y\odot I){\tt1}$$

Comment: $A(Y)$ is linear in Y